# Where to obtain termios.h

Tags: mingw, termios, termcap

In my particular situation, I am using `MinGW/MSys`. It doesn't contain `termios.h`. Turns out that it isn't a library that can be downloaded and installed (Google didn't found any). `Termcap` also doesn't include `termios.h`.

From where can I get this file?

Comment: Comment below not withstanding, is there a terminos version available for mingw?

Answer (score 7):

MinGW doesnt fully support POSIX and therefore termios.h is missing.

On the other side, Cygwin is capable of POSIX and termios.h.