# Cygwin cannot find termios.h

Tags: cygwin, termios

I use Code blocks 20.03 at windows 10 64 bit, using cygwin32 bit and i am trying to include `#include <termios.h>` bit it gives me `fatal error: sys/termios.h: No such file or directory`

I thought cygwin would have termios and i could include it by default, according to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772965/where-to-obtain-termios-h) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the proper `devel` package:

```
$ cygcheck -p "sys/termios.h"
Found 11 matches for sys/termios.h
cygwin-devel-3.0.7-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
...
cygwin-devel-3.1.7-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-3.2.0-0.1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
...
```

install the `cygwin-devel` package where all the cygwin headers are included

```
$ cygcheck -c cygwin-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin-devel         3.1.7-1        OK

$ cygcheck -l cygwin-devel |grep termios
/usr/include/termios.h
/usr/include/machine/termios.h
/usr/include/sys/termios.h
```